# floating action button in linearlayout not showing

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Hello I am trying to align a floating action button to the bottom right of the screen but its showing on the right top corner of the screen what can i do to make it to the bottom right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/createRoomButton"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="Search Rooms">
        <requestFocus />
    </SearchView>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pullToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/roomList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>






</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `LinearLayout` doesn't allow overlapping children. It'll just stack them edge to edge. You'll want to use a `ViewGroup` that does; e.g., `RelativeLayout`, `CoordinatorLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have made the necessary changes for your UI and now it works perfectly:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/createRoomButton"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="22dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>



    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:queryHint="Search Rooms">
        <requestFocus />
    </SearchView>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pullToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/roomList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]